# Java Swing Horse Simulation

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, simulation

I am having problem getting my horse position to update within my swing application. I have tried multiple methods to update the xPosition of the horses as they refresh across the swing panel that represents the racetrack.

```
public class HorseModel{

    /*Horse dimensions*/
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private final int horsePerimeter = 20;

    public HorseModel(int xT, int yT){
    /*Constructor*/
        x = xT;
        y = yT;
    }
    public void setDimensions(int dimX, int dimY){
    /*Sets program dimensions*/
        x = dimX;
        y = dimY;
    }
    public void createHorse(Graphics2D h){
    /*Paints HorseModel on screen as 2 dimensional object*/

        Ellipse2D.Double horseModel = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, horsePerimeter, horsePerimeter);
        h.setColor(Color.RED);
        h.fill(horseModel);
        h.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        h.draw(horseModel);
    }
}
public class HorseMovement implements Runnable{

    public final int xStartPos = 10; //change
    public final int yStartPos = 20;

    private RaceTrack hRaceTrack;
    private HorseModel Horse2D;
    private int xPos, yPos;

    public HorseMovement(RaceTrack r, int yPos_Spacing){
    /*Constructor*/
        xPos = xStartPos;
        yPos = yStartPos * yPos_Spacing;
        Horse2D = new HorseModel(xPos, yPos);
        hRaceTrack = r;
    }
    public HorseModel moveHorse(HorseModel horseObject){
    /*Updates horse positon*/
        horseObject = new HorseModel(xPos++, yPos);
        return horseObject;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics h){
    /*paints the new horse after movement*/
        this.Horse2D = moveHorse(Horse2D);
        Graphics2D hMod = (Graphics2D) h;
        Horse2D.createHorse(hMod);
    }
    public void run(){
    /*Repaints the horse models as they increment movement across the screen*/
        hRaceTrack.repaint();
        hRaceTrack.revalidate();
    }
}
public class RacePanel extends JFrame{

    /*Frame Buttons*/
    private JPanel mPanel;
    private JButton startRace = new JButton("Start Race");
    private JButton stopRace = new JButton("Stop Race");
    private JButton startOver = new JButton("Start Over");


    /*Panel to fill with HorseModels for race*/
    private RaceTrack rTrack;

    /*Window dimensions*/
    public int Window_Height = 1024;
    public int Window_Width = 768;

    public RacePanel(){
    /*Constructor*/

        initGui();
        initRace();
        initQuit();

        setSize(Window_Width, Window_Height);
    }
    public void initGui(){
    /*Initializes the main race panel and sets button positions and layouts*/
        mPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        rTrack = new RaceTrack();

        JPanel horsePanel = new JPanel(); //panel to house horse objects before running across screen

        horsePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

        positionJPanels(horsePanel, mPanel);
    }
    public void initRace(){
    /*implements action listener for start race button*/
        class StartRace implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                startRace.setEnabled(true);
                rTrack.initTrack();
            }
        }
        ActionListener event = new StartRace();
        stopRace.addActionListener(event);
    }
    public void initQuit(){
    /*Implements the action listener for stop race button*/
        class StopRace implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.exit(0);//exits program if race is stopped
            }
        }
        ActionListener event = new StopRace();
        stopRace.addActionListener(event);
    }
    public void positionJPanels(JPanel h, JPanel p){
    /*Handles adding buttons to a JPanel*/
        h.add(startRace);
        h.add(startOver);
        h.add(stopRace);

        p.add(h, BorderLayout.NORTH); //sets the horse panel buttons to the top of the layout
        p.add(rTrack, BorderLayout.CENTER); //sets

        add(p);
    }
}

public class RaceController {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new RaceController();
    }
    public RaceController(){
    /*Constructor*/
        JFrame mFrame = new RacePanel();
        mFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
public class RaceTrack extends JPanel{

    /*Sets horses within race track*/
    private int numOfHorseObjects = 5;// change this to a dynamic
    private int numOfThreads = 25;

    /*Holds horse thread from HorseObject class*/
    private ArrayList<HorseMovement> horses = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList(numOfThreads);

    public RaceTrack(){
    /*Constructor*/
        setBackground(Color.black);
        reset();
    }
    public void initTrack(){
    /*Starts the RaceTrack simulation*/
        threads.clear(); //clears the thread arraylist still residing

        for(int i = 0; i < horses.size(); i++){
            Thread T = new Thread(horses.get(i));
            T.start();
            threads.add(T);
        }
    }
    public void reset(){
    /*resets horse position within screen*/
        horses.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfHorseObjects; i++){
            horses.add(new HorseMovement(this, i + 1));
        }
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    /*overrides graphics paint method in order to paint the horse movements
    * through the arraylist of HorseMovements*/
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for(HorseMovement h : horses){
            h.paintComponent(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issues with your code:

- You never give the startRace JButton an ActionListener, so how is button going to have any affect, and how is the race ever going to start? Note that you're adding the StartRace ActionListener object to the stopRace JButton, and I'm guessing that this was done in error.
- Even if you added that Listener to the startRace button, the action listener will only advance all the horses one "step" and no more -- there are no loops in within your background threads to perform actions repetitively.
- You seem to be creating new Horse2D objects needlessly. Why not simply advance the location of the existing Horse2D object?
- Myself, I'd use a single Swing Timer rather than a bunch of Threads in order to simplify the code.